# Custom file with special code of category widget

Tags: categories, widgets

Is any way to define custom code/file of standard `class-wp-widget-categories.php` for my theme?

In standard WP `class-wp-widget-categories.php` list is printed in simple `<ul>` tag. I need to add special CSS class for this tag but only for my theme, but not for all widgets loaded from this file. So I came up with that in directory structure of my theme I could have replacement file with custom code.

Any help?

Comment: I don't see `<ul>` tag In standard WP `class-wp-widget-calendar.php`

Comment: Sorry - my FAULT. `categories`!